# Padding tables with 0s in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table of the form:

```
id |  A | B |  C
 -----------------
 1 |  1 | 0 |  1
 1 |  2 | 1 |  0
 2 |  1 | 4 |  0
```

I would like to pad this table with rows of 0s (excluding the id) such that each id has exactly 3 entries. So the result would be:

```
id |  A | B |  C
 -----------------
 1 |  0 | 0 |  0
 1 |  1 | 0 |  1
 1 |  2 | 1 |  0
 2 |  0 | 0 |  0
 2 |  0 | 0 |  0
 2 |  1 | 4 |  0
```

This is because id 1 had two entries, so we added one row of 0s, and id 2 had one entry, so we added two rows of 0s.

Note: we can assume each id occurs no more than 3 times and that if an id occurs exactly 3 times, there is no need to add padding.

Is there an intelligent way of doing this with Amazon Redshift? I need this to scale to 30 days of padding and a few hundred columns.

Comment: so if an id has 3 rows..you don't need to add a 0's row..is that correct?

Comment: @vkp: Correct, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

If column A is always sequential you can do:

```
select i.id, n.num,
       coalesce(t.b, 0) as b,
       coalesce(t.c, 0) as c
from (select distinct id from t) i cross join
     (select 1 as num union all select 2 union all select 3) n left join
     t on i.id = t.id and n.num = t.A;
```

You do need to list each column in the `select` to get the zeros.

If the above is not true, you can make it true with a CTE:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as num
      from t
     )
select i.id, coalesce(t.a, 0) as a,
       coalesce(t.b, 0) as b,
       coalesce(t.c, 0) as c
from (select distinct id from t) i cross join
     (select 1 as num union all select 2 union all select 3) n left join 
     t on i.id = t.id and n.num = t.num;
```